# Can member functions be called within another one, while those functions' implementation are separated from class definition themselves?

Tags: c++, member-functions

I'd like to have a class which a member function is called from antoher member function, like this code below:

```
class test
{
    public:
      void ini();
      void itu();
}

void test::ini()
{
    cout << test::itu() << endl;
}

void test::itu()
{
    cout << 5 << endl;
}
```

Is that code above correct? Or any suggestions to improve?

I'm using GCC 7.1.0

Comment: Yes, member functions can call orher member functions. But, ditch the "test::" in "test::itu()".

Comment: This code is correct. @Jesper Juhl suggests dropping `test::` as the compiler searches for the function `itu()` in a way that finds the function in the class first. If you want to make it clear that you use the class method then using the `this` pointer is the way to go (`this->itu()`). You should also not use `endl` unless you are mixing C++ output with C-style output, use just `'\n'`.

Comment: @JustinFinnerty: That's just not true. Calling virtual functions in a constructor is not undefined behaviour. It's considered dangerous, yes, but not because the behaviour is undefined but because the behaviour is not what one might expect (i.e. there is no dispatch to the derived-class implementation). See https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/strange-inheritance#calling-virtuals-from-ctors

Comment: @Christian Hackl you are right. I didn't want to go in to too much detail about what happens in constructors, but to say it was UB was too extreme. I will give the link you give next time. I will rewrite my comment.

Comment: The only time you have to be careful calling one method from another is in the constructor. In the constructor it is best not to call any __virtual__ methods, see [calling virtual functions in ctors](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/strange-inheritance#calling-virtuals-from-ctors). This includes not calling a __non-virtual__ method that calls a __virtual__ method.